# Isomorphism between tensor product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, vector-space-isomorphism

While I am familiar with the isomorphism between finite-dimensional vector spaces with the same dimension and isometric isomorphism between Hilbert spaces, I realize I am getting confused by $n$-th tensor products of an infinite-dimensional separable  Hilbert space $H$ ($H^{\otimes n} = \underbrace{H \otimes \dots \otimes H }_{\text{$n$ times}}$).

Is $H^{\otimes n}$ isomorph to $H^{\otimes m}$ for $ m \ne n$?

Since every separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space is isomorph to $\ell_2$, they should be isomorph. However, I have not been able to identify a bijection between  $H^{\otimes n}$ and  $H^{\otimes m}$ which preserves  the algebraic structure. Pretty sure that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: This certainly isn't true if $H$ is finite dimensional since then the various tensor powers have different dimensions. In the infinite dimensional case, try taking an orthonormal basis for $H$, using it to build an orthonormal basis for $H^{\otimes 2}$ and then constructing a bijection between them.

Comment: What "tensor product" do you mean, for Hilbert spaces? Just the purely algebraic one? Or with Hilbert-Schmidt norm and completed, to again be a Hilbert space? (The latter is _not_ a genuine tensor product in the category of Hilbert spaces...)

Comment: @paulgarrett  I am interested in the case of the tensor product  being again a Hilbert space.